# Meteor.js: Deps.autorun and subscriptions

Tags: meteor

I've recently picked up MeteorJs and really dig it. I've gotten 99% of my app to work, except for this one nagging bug (I've been chasing it for two days now).

The issue is logging in, or more appropriately, what happens after a user signs in, or when a user creates an account. My code below works, but it appears to be a timing issue of sorts.

If I take out the containing call to `Deps.autorun`, sign in fails as it doesn't find a room.
BUT, if then creating an account fails as it doesn't have a user profile. Note that even when it fails, I can refresh the page and everything works. I've stepped through the code a hundred times and this has to be it.

Anything glaringly obvious?

```
Deps.autorun ->
  if Meteor.user()
    user   = Meteor.user()
    userId = Meteor.userId()
    email  = user.emails[0].address

    Meteor.subscribe "rooms", email

    if user.profile is undefined
      if Rooms.findOne() is undefined
        roomId = Rooms.insert({name: "Watercooler", ownerId: userId, inviteeEmails: [], roster: []})
      else
        roomId = Rooms.findOne()._id

      Meteor.users.update({_id: userId}, {$set:{'profile.lastRoomId': roomId, 'profile.showGravatars': true}})
    else
      roomId = user.profile.lastRoomId

    Meteor.subscribe "connections"
    Meteor.subscribe "messages", roomId
    Meteor.subscribe "last_in_room", roomId
    Meteor.call 'addUserToRoster', roomId

    Meteor.setInterval ->
      Meteor.call 'keepalive', userId
    , 5000
```

Comment: If the code is executed on the client, and I assume this is the case since you're using subscriptions, the `Room.insert` returns `udefined`. To get the the right `_id` you'll need to pass a callback to the `insert` method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating the room when the user signs up?  Look at this bit on the create user hooks: http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_oncreateuser.

Answer (score 0):

Looks messy, why not do inserts and updates on the server in Meteor.methods, when a user is created.

I don't think you gain anything by having 1/2 this code in Deps.autorun, also. take out the following:
    Meteor.subscribe "connections"

This doesn't need to be in Deps.autorun. And this line could probably find a better home:
    Meteor.call 'addUserToRoster', roomId

Like in:
    Accounts.onCreateUser(func)
http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_oncreateuser